# org-id-find unable to find existing ID

Tags: org-mode

After having moved to an upgraded machine, I am now facing problems with my org-mode setup, specifically that `org-id-find` now returns ***nil*** for IDs that **do** exists in my org files. This breaks some of my functions (where it is used in conjunction with `org-with-point-at`), as they are unable to find the correct headings.

On emacs 24.5.1/org-mode 8.2.10, `org-id-find` returns ***(file-name . position)*** as it should, but on emacs 25.2.2/org-mode 9.1.6, `org-id-find` returns ***nil***. The configuration files are the same.

`org-id-track-globally` is set to *t*, and I can see in ***Messages*** that files are searched for IDs. The file system in which my org files are located are the same on both machines (it's mounted from a central file server with NFS). `org-id-locations-file` is set and I have tried running `org-id-update-id-locations` to no avail.

I haven't been able to find any explantion for this behaviour. Anyone experienced anything similar?

Comment: Although I don't use them, I'd say you'll need to define the variable which tell what files are going to be tracked and redo the tracking file (?) using `org-id-update-id-locations`.

Comment: @Muihlinn is correct I believe: do `C-h v org-id-locations-file` for more info. If the files are in the same locations in the new filesystem, you should be able to just copy that file from the old machine to the new machine and reuse it. Otherwise, you will have to reconstruct it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the file system in which my org files are located is on NFS, so the locations are the same on both machines. And ```org-id-locaitons-file``` is set and I have already tried with ```org-id-update-id-locations``` to no avail. I have updated my question.